# Is there any connection between the minimum vertex cover and the size of longest path in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

If we know the size of the minimum vertex cover for a general graph $G$ is $\tau(G)$, can we define any connectivity/formula between $\tau(G)$ and its longest path?

Comment: The complete graph has a path of length $n$ yet has minimum vertex cover of size 1. While a path graph has a minimum vertex cover of size $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Meanwhile if we take a star graph on $n/2+1$ vertices, and subdivide all its edges, it has has minimum cover $n/2$ yet maximum path 4. What kind of phenomena are you expecting?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Sorry, but you are wrong. The minimum vertex cover size for a complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n-1$ (not 1). Also, the minimum vertex cover in a star graph is $1$.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter By the way, I am looking for a formula in a general graph without any extra assumptions on $G$.

Comment: Oh I see, I believe I was confused with the vertex domination number or something. Regardless, the claims about paths and subdivided stars should hold, so there doesn't seem to be much that can be said in general when the vertex cover is large.

Comment: Well, the minimum vertex cover is at least half the length of a longest path.  So if the vertex cover number is small, then so is the length of the longest path.  But as pointed out with the subdivided star, having large vertex cover number doesn't mean you have a long path

Comment: @LouisD Thanks, Louis. That's a good point.